# Button Click in Bootstrap, how to toggle class of nav?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to setup a wizard-style theme on one of my pages for building a profile, and I want to be able to toggle the class of the pill nav on bootstrap by clicking next, although I am not entirely sure how to do so. My `nav` for the tabs layout is like this:

```
<!-- Nav tabs -->
<ul class="nav nav-pills" role="tablist">
    <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#aaa" aria-controls="aaa" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">aaa</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#bbb" aria-controls="bbb" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">bbb</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#ccc" aria-controls="ccc" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">ccc</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#ddd" aria-controls="ddd" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">ddd</a></li>
</ul>
```

My buttons look something like this, and they work, but they don't toggle the `"active"` class on the corresponding `nav-pills`:

```
<a href="#bbb" aria-controls="bbb" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" class="btn btn-success btn-lg bottomright">Next</a>
```

Is there a way I an target the `nav-pills` to toggle the active class?

Comment: I tried throwing a JSFiddle together but its not taking on the functionality of my page.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.nav-tabs > .active').next('li').find('a').trigger('click');
```

This JQuery code in next button click may helps you to set next item in list as active.
Also i think that you should remove `href="#bbb"` from 'Next' button.